# Angular Gantt - How to set from-date and to-date range to show only required minutes?

Tags: angularjs, gantt-chart

I am working an Angular Gantt Charts. I set my Gantt chart headers to show only minutes. Also I want to set from minutes and to minutes range. I have coded like below. But It always display the entire day view as minutes. Any idea? to show only the range in minutes? and Is It possible to show the headers in milliseconds?

```js
$scope.options = {
 fromDate:new Date(2013, 10, 15, 14, 0, 0),
 toDate:new Date(2013, 10, 15, 17, 50, 0)}

 $scope.data = [   
    {name: 'row2', tasks: [
        {name: 'task3', from: new Date(2013, 10, 15, 15, 0, 0), to: new Date(2013, 10, 15, 15, 10, 0)},
        {name: 'task4', from: new Date(2013, 10, 15, 16, 20, 0), to: new Date(2013, 10, 15, 16, 50, 0)}
      ]
    }
]
```

```html
<div gantt data="data" from-date = "options.fromDate" to-date = "options.toDate" headers="['minute']" >
<gantt-tree>  </gantt-tree> </div>
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you get it working?

Comment: @Skanda nope it didnt work yet

Comment: @Skanda Is there any other plugin is there for angular to show milliseconds in headers?? my duration range only in milliseconds and seconds??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add milliseconds to your header. But there seems to be an issue that the range is always from start of day to end of day.

Add headers and headersFormats to your div

```html
<div gantt data="data" from-date = "options.fromDate" to-date = "options.toDate" headers="['seconds', 'milliseconds']" headers-formats="headersFormats">
<gantt-tree>  </gantt-tree> </div>
```

In your controller define the headerFormats as follows

```js
$scope.headersFormats = {
  seconds: function(column) {
    return column.date.format('ss');
  },
  milliseconds: function(column) {
    return column.date.format('SSS');
  }
};
```

Comment: It wont be loaded after setting up milliseconds in header

Comment: how to rectify the range issue(start and end date)

Comment: Start end date I am still exploring

Comment: Is there any other gantt chart to display ordinal values in headers?instead of timescale?

Comment: We couldn't get it working with Angular-Gantt and built our own gantt.

Comment: can you share me the details. using which framework is easy to construct this? only d3 is enough?